# SQL Server 2008 - Split

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

How do we use cross apply and split values in a column?

I have a function dbo.split that based on a comma separates the values into separate column

```
 Id         Name      Value  
1234    A     6767  
1234    A     6767,1111   
5678    A     6767  
5678    A     6767,1111  
9999    A     6767
```

Please help with SQL query to Cross Apply and also use the split function

Thanks

Comment: You need to tell us what the expected result is, I think.

Comment: In order for us to be able to answer your question, you need to add some more information. Right now there isn't enough detail included for anyone to do much more than guess :)

Comment: It seems like the OP vandalized his/her own question... I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to use the split function with a column as a parameter.

```
SELECT pd.contentnodeid,
       pt.name,
       s.Value
FROM   vw_abc pd
       INNER JOIN propertytype pt
         ON pd.propertytypeid = pt.id
       INNER JOIN tab t
         ON t.id = pt.tabid
       INNER JOIN contenttype ct
         ON ct.nodeid = pt.contenttypeid
       INNER JOIN propertytype pt1
         ON pt1.name = pt.name
       INNER JOIN vw_abc pd1
         ON pd1.propertytypeid = pt1.id
       CROSS APPLY dbo.split(',', pd1.datanvarchar) as s
WHERE  t.TEXT LIKE 'ANC'
       AND pd1.datanvarchar <> 'NULL'
       AND pd1.datanvarchar <> ''
       AND pd.datanvarchar LIKE '%'
       AND pd1.datanvarchar LIKE '%'
```

Comment: Thanks as always Mikael...will revert

Comment: 2740 A 6767    
2740 A 6767,2801
2788 A 6767    
2788 A 6767,2801
2790 A 6767    
2790 A 6767,2801
2800 A 6767    
2800 A 6767,2801
3215 A 6767    
3215 A 6767,2801 - This is the output I am getting

Comment: @user - Remove the `split`part and make sure you are getting the rows you need first. BTW I think I "accidentally" removed the `distinct` from you query.

Comment: Yes I am getting the desired rows...even on commenting the cross apply row...I still get the same records I want to split 6767,2801 to two separate rows

Comment: No..Thanks Excellent tip...got the result